# Solarisで0byteファイルのみを削除するコマンドについて

Tags: solaris

Solaris11.3環境です。
以下のような構成のディレクトリがあるとします。

`/var/tmp/KOTEI/END/`
`/var/tmp/組織コード/END/`

この配下にシステムでファイルが大量に作成されるのですが、その中には0byteのファイルも含まれます。
この0byteファイルが1ヶ月で10万個近く溜まってしまうので、シェルで自動削除しようと考えています。
ファイル名に関わらず、0byteファイルは全て削除します。

以下のようなコマンドを考えたのですが、問題ないかご意見いただけないでしょうか？

`find /var/tmp/KOTEI/END -size 0c -exec rm {} \;`
`find /var/tmp/*/END -size 0c -exec rm {} \;`

一番怖いのは、0byteでない、データが含まれているファイルも誤って削除してしまうことです。
また、組織は変更になる可能性があるため、"/*/"にすることで対応できているか不安です。

是非アドバイスの程、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `find`コマンドでいきなり`-exec rm`で削除する代わりに、findの結果を`-ls`で期待する結果を確認してはどうでしょうか？ / また、配下のディレクトリサイズがどれくらいになるのかわかりませんが、削除の前に念のためアーカイブでバックアップしておく、という方法も考えられます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.itmedia.co.jp/qa9620068.html

Answer (score 3):

問題ありません。

Solaris の `find`(1) の `-exec` は `+` が使えるので、場合によっては `;` より効率的に処理できます。`;` だとファイル数だけ `rm`(1) が起動されますが、`+` なら数回で済みます。詳細はオンラインマニュアルを読んでください。

```
$ find /path/to/target/dir -size 0c -exec rm {} +
```

処理対象ファイルを確認したいなら `-exec` なし、あるいは `-exec` の代わりに `-ls` を指定、あるいは `rm` の前に `echo` を付ければ事前に確認できます。

```
$ find /path/to/target/dir -size 0c
...サイズ 0 のファイルの名前一覧が表示される...
$ find /path/to/target/dir -size 0c -ls
...サイズ 0 のファイルの `ls -l` 相当一覧が表示される...
$ find /path/to/target/dir -size 0c -exec echo rm {} +
... `rm <サイズ 0 のファイル名一式...>` が表示される...
```